# How to add dynamic key value pair in existing json object in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to know how to add dynamic key/value pair in an Json array of objects  during execution.

`$result2` is from database query results

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) )
{
 $result_show[]=$row;
 $result_show[]['ismy']='1';
 $result_show[]['time']='close';
 $result_show[]['img']  = $path;
}
```

My Result is:

```
{"results":[{"id":"412"},{"ismy":"0"},{"time":"close"},{"img":"1.JPG"}]}
```

Desired Result is:

```
{"results":[{"id":"412","ismy":"0","time":"close","img":"1.JPG"}]}
```

Whats wrong with this? Please help me out.

Comment: yes got the answer  and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :-

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) ) {
{
    $result_show[$i]=$row;
    $result_show[$i]['ismy']='1';
    $result_show[$i]['time']='close';
    $result_show[$i]['img']  = $path;
     $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you are using the shortened version of the [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function four times. What you really want to do is add one single element to the results array, try it with:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) ) {
  $row['ismy']   = '1';
  $row['time']   = 'close';
  $row['img']    = $path;
  $result_show[] = $row;
}
```